# Couple the data in all possible combinations

Tags: python, r, vba, python-3.x, openrefine

I have data in column in two columns like this

```
Id  Value
1   a
2   f
1   c
1   h
2   a
```

and I'd like couple the data of the 'Value' column in all possible combinations based on the same Id such as

```
(a,c)
(a,h)
(c,h)
(f,a)
```

Is there any R or Python or VBA code to get this task?

Comment: is the data entered manually or read from a file?

Comment: @depperm I'd like enter the data from a file like csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a character matrix with these combinations using base R, try

```
do.call(rbind, t(sapply(split(df, df$Id), function(i) t(combn(i$Value, 2)))))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "c" 
[2,] "a"  "h" 
[3,] "c"  "h" 
[4,] "f"  "a"
```

Each row is a desired combination.

To break this down a bit, `split` splits the data.frame by Id into a list of two data.frames. Then `sapply` is fed this list and the `combn` function to find the pairwise combinations within these data.frames. The result from each data.frame (which is a matrix) is transposed to fit your desired structure using `t`. Finally, this list of matrices is fed to `do.call` which uses `rbind` to return the final matrix.

*Note*: There is an assumption that the value column is character (not the pesky factor variable type). This is easily accomplished in the `read.` family of functions, like `read.csv` and `read.table` by adding the as.is=TRUE argument to your read function (or the longer stringsAsFactors=FALSE). If the variable is already a factor, you can wrap the `i$Value` statement near the end in `as.character`: `as.character(i$Value)` and it will run as desired.

Comment: @Imo Amazing but what if I want enter the data from a file eg. CSV

Comment: @AndreaAngeli This should not be a problem. Just use `df <- read.csv(..., as.is=TRUE)` and you should be fine. I'll add an additional note in my answer.

Comment: @Imo it works well but I'd like also to get the output data in a CSV format how can I? Sorry, but I'm a newbie on R ;)

Comment: To write it out, just use `myMat <- do.call(rbind, ...)` with the stuff from above. then `write.csv(myMat, ...)`. `write.csv` will take matrices (see `?write.csv` for additional arguments like the necessary `file=` argument. To give the matrix row or column names, use `rownames(myMat) <- c(...)` or `colnames(myMat) <- c(...)` where `c()` defines a character vector of the same dimension as your row or column.

Comment: @Imo Amazing! Thank you so much. R is a language very very powerful! :)

Comment: @Imo update: I tried whit the dataset above and it works fine but with another dataset more long when I try to run `myMat <- do.call(rbind, t(sapply(split(df, df$Id), function(i) t(combn(i$Value, 2)))))` returns `Error in combn(i$Value, 2) : n < m` Why?

Comment: This sounds like your variable is not named Value as it was in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Using `R` you could try:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  split(.$Id) %>%
  map(~ t(combn(.$Value, 2)))
```

Which gives:

```
#$`1`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "c" 
#[2,] "a"  "h" 
#[3,] "c"  "h" 
#
#$`2`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] f    a   
#Levels: a c f h
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way (possibly slightly faster as it exploits the fact that you're looking for all *pairs*, and avoids `combn` and `t`):

```
require(data.table)
dt[, .( c1 = rep(Value, (.N:1)-1L), c2 = rep(Value, (1:.N)-1L) ), by=Id]
#    Id c1 c2
# 1:  1  a  c
# 2:  1  a  h
# 3:  1  c  h
# 4:  2  f  a
```

`.N` contains the number of observations for each group.

---

where dt is:

```
dt = fread('Id  Value
1   a
2   f
1   c
1   h
2   a')
```

Comment: if I want to enter the data by an externa csv is the code the same?